# Convergence of $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{a_j}{j}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've come to the following exercise. Let $a_j$ be a non-negative sequence. Suppose we know that $\lim_n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\rightarrow 0$. Is it true that $\lim_n\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_j}{j}<\infty$?

I didn't go very far. It felt right to use Cauchy-Schwartz and write something like
$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_j}{j} = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{a_i\sqrt{n}}{j\sqrt{n}}\leq (\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2/n)^{1/2}(\sum_{j=1}^n n/j^2)^{1/2}$, but I'm not sure we can conclude $\lim_n(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2/n)^{1/2}<\infty$ from the claim?

Comment: Summation by parts may help. I mean ${a_j\over j}={S_{j+1}-S_j\over j }$ where $S_j=\sum_{i=1}^ja_j.$

Comment: Thanks. I can see that with this decomposition we can write study the convergence of $\sum a_j/j$ in terms of $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^j a_i}{\sqrt{j}}$, we do know that $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^j a_i}{\sqrt{j}}$ vanishes, but how does the claim follow? What am I missing?

Comment: I have posted an answer. Concerning your attempt the limit you were not sure of is equal  $0,$ however the second factor behaves like $\sqrt{n},$ which is an obstacle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S_0=0$ and $S_j=\sum_{i=1}^ja_i.$ We have $$\sum_{j=1}^n{a_j\over j}= \sum_{j=1}^n{S_j-S_{j-1}\over j}\\
=\sum_{j=1}^n{S_j\over j}-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{S_j\over j+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{S_j\over j(j+1)}+{S_n\over n}$$ By assumptions $S_j\le cj^{1/2}.$ Hence the last expression can be bounded above by
$$c\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} {1\over j\sqrt{j}}+c{1\over \sqrt{n}}\le c\sum_{j=1}^\infty {1\over j\sqrt{j}}+c$$ Therefore the series $\sum {a_j\over j}$ is convergent.